# Debezium can not authorize the Mongodb shards

Tags: mongodb, debezium, cdc

I created a MongoDb sharded cluster with 2 shards and one of the shards is in another guest machine. The cluster has authorization enabled. And just to solve this problem I created a super user with *root* role. What Im trying is to create a connector by this config and create my topics;

```
            {
            "name": "pms-20",
            "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
                "mongodb.connection.string":"mongodb://user2:1@192.168.2.5:27030/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&authSource=admin&directConnection=true",
                "topic.prefix": "eys",
                "mongodb.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
                "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.2.4:29092",
                "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
                "collection.include.list": "wins.business,wins.tasks",
                "capture.mode": "change_streams_with_pre_image"
            }
        }
```

My mongos is exposed on 27030. But when I send this request to the debezium Im getting these errors

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command aggregate requires authentication' on server 192.168.2.5:27023. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command aggregate requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized", "lastCommittedOpTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1709881534, "i": 1}}, "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1709881541, "i": 2}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "7fJJ7z0jglTmQUik3fL7bAndAxk=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7343563481024561176}}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1709881534, "i": 1}}}

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command aggregate requires authentication' on server 192.168.2.4:27020. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command aggregate requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized", "lastCommittedOpTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1709881535, "i": 1}}, "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1709881541, "i": 2}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "7fJJ7z0jglTmQUik3fL7bAndAxk=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7343563481024561176}}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1709881535, "i": 1}}}
```

I tried various roles and privileges but alas didnt work.
Debezium version: 2.4
MongoDb version: 6.0
They are both dockerized.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the [Shard Local User](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/core/core/security-users/#shard-local-users)? See [Create the shard-local user administrator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/core/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/#create-the-shard-local-user-administrator-optional)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I created the same role and users at primary nodes of the configvsr and shards so that authentication would be consistent all accross the cluster.

Comment: The it should work. Can you connect with `mongosh`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit brother I already identified the problem, solved it and posted it in the answer. And I also found the role I need and started using it. Thanks for your interest ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I need specify the connection mode to sharded. I thought it would discover the cluster but I was wrong. The ports of the shards got me thinking and I asked myself why the heck does it trying to connect to shards, theres a mongo server up and running. And then I looked to the [documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.4/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-connector-properties) again see that

```
replica_set: The connector establishes individual connections to the replica set for each shard.
sharded: The connector establishes a single connection to the database, based on the value of the mongodb.connection.string.
```

Its default is set to replica_set and it was trying to connect to each shard. It worked perfectly when I added this line

```
"mongodb.connection.mode":"sharded",
```

It works now but I need to find out which role and privilege would suit my needs.